# eth0:0 is configured but not listed in ifconfig output

Tags: networking, ifconfig, eth0

I have the following problem:

My server was given two IPs from [b]different[/b] subnets. Now I am trying to configure the system to work properly. I have created

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
# Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
HWADDR=00:30:48:DA:B1:0E
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=79.174.69.255
IPADDR=79.174.69.241
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
NETWORK=79.174.68.0
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=79.174.68.1
TYPE=Ethernet

[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0
# Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
HWADDR=00:30:48:DA:B1:0E
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=79.174.69.255
IPADDR=79.174.71.74
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=79.174.71.1
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=79.174.71.1
TYPE=Ethernet
```

But both after "service network restart" and after "reboot"

```
[root@server ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:DA:B1:0E
          inet addr:79.174.71.74  Bcast:79.174.71.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::230:48ff:feda:b10e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:910284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:257964879 (246.0 MiB)  TX bytes:232450 (227.0 KiB)
          Memory:df220000-df240000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6976 (6.8 KiB)  TX bytes:6976 (6.8 KiB)
```

Device eth0:0 is not shown as active. If I try

```
[root@server ~]# ifconfig eth0:0
eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:DA:B1:0E
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:df220000-df240000
```

It is shown as up and running, but IP is not assigned to it.

Also it is strange, that IP address assigned to eth0:0 in config file is used by eth0.

/var/log/messages shows nothing about network configuration errors on either eth0 or eth0:0. system-config-network seem to understand all settings correctly and resaves them ok also.

"ifup eth0:0" executes ok, but ifconfig afterwards shows no eth0:0 device after that.

What did I do wrong? May be the problem is that IPs are from different subnets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>`eth0` and `eth0:0` are the same interface. Use `eth0:1` for an alias.</strike>

Could it be that `DEVICE=eth0` should actually be `DEVICE=eth0:0`?

Comment: Well spotted :)

Comment: That is not correct: http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-6133 | http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html | http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IP-Alias.html
eth0:0 is a correct alias. My second CentOS server is using it and works ok.

Comment: @FractalizeR: I remember I stopped eth0:0 by mistake once and it brought down the whole interface, but it was on Ubuntu. Or I remember wrong. Anyway, I have edited the post with a different attempt.

Comment: Yes, I've just spotted that it should be DEVICE=eth0:0! The problem arose when I misconfigured IPs on network card and asked hoster to correct this problem and to bring up second IP on virtual adapter. My god..

Comment: @FractalizeR: Don't be so hard on yourself. I had to drive to the colo place because a server would not come up for a similar misconfiguration... and Ubuntu will fail all interfaces if one is misconfigured...